# Can't export imported types in TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to split a long file into multiple ones, without impacting the structure of the imports.

I have an interface exported on `module-b`, like so:

```
export interface A {
    // stuff
}
```

In my "module-collection" file, I have the following:

```
export { A } from './module-b'
```

However, I'm getting the following error on compilation:

```
./module-collection.ts
Attempted import error: 'A' is not exported from './module-b.ts'.
```

**Importing the interface on `module-collection.ts` works and I can use it, but trying to export causes this error.**

I tried to import/export more verbosely, like so:

```
import { A } from 'module-b'
export { A }
```

And I also tried aliasing them, like so:

```
import { A as AA } from 'module-b'
export { AA as A }
```

Which shows the same error.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to do this? For now, I will have to directly import from the original files, but I would have rathered keep the original structure of imports.

Comment: This works pretty well for me. Are you sure you're writing everything correctly? At least your last `import ` statement is a bit different from your first (not local, and included a .ts)

Comment: @Evert the last `.ts` is a mistake, I don't use file extensions at all in my project. I obfuscated the names but it is essentially the same, this happens on both `interface` and `type` exports, but regular JS functions/classes export properly and without issue